# PHP cent use global variable in class method

Tags: php, class, oop, variables, global-variables

i am trying to make `$var1` to work on many different method

`var1` is outcome of `extract()` from an array that contains url parts

exp:

$url = 'localhost/site/className/edit/254/...';

$arr[var1] = 'edit';

$arr[var2] = '254';

```
$var1 = 'something';

class myClass{
    function doSomething(){
        echo $var1;
    }
}

$obj = new myClass();
$obj->doSomething();
```

output:

Notice: Undefined variable: var1 in....

is there any way to fix it??

Comment: did you read http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php ?

Comment: you're going to need to pass `var1` into that method to use it...  read the link about variable scope in the first comment.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it doesn't look like the poster has read any of the PHP documentation before asking

Comment: I have read and searched, Just did not explain the problem further..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

2 ways to fix it:

First, the best - passing variables as function arguments:

```
$var1 = 'something';

class myClass{
    function doSomething($var){
        echo $var;
    }
}

$obj = new myClass(); //You could also pass it to constructor
$obj->doSomething($var1);
```

Second, working, but is considered to be a **bad practice**:

```
$var1 = 'something';

class myClass{
    function doSomething(){
        global $var1 ;
        echo $var1;
    }
}

$obj = new myClass();
$obj->doSomething();
```

Comment: i am trying to make `$var1` to work on many different methods

Comment: Then make it an instance variable.

Comment: For a unit test, second solution is acceptable :)